# how can I write IF statement in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I have a table with `type` field.

how can I check this field in query:

I want to check it if `type` == 'a'

then `bes`=`amount`,`bed` = '-'

ELSE `bed`=`amount`,`bes` = '-'

bes and bed is not really exists in my table but amount is (int)

this is my try:

```
SELECT billing.*,
    CASE billing.type WHEN 'A' THEN billing.amount AS bes, '-' AS bed ELSE billing.amount AS bed, '-' AS bes END
    FROM billing
```

... my searches wasn't useful

any solution...

Comment: As you can see, we are all very much in agreement about the proper solution here :-)

Comment: thats good... when I try this in separate query, there is no problem but in my project ... error

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create condition for every row, `MySQL` supports *inline* `IF` statements.

```
SELECT billing.*,
       IF(billing.type = 'A', billing.amount, '-') AS bes,
       IF(billing.type = 'A', '-', billing.amount) AS bed
FROM   billing
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need two case statements for that:

```
SELECT billing.*,
  CASE billing.type WHEN 'A' THEN billing.amount ELSE '-' AS bes END,
  CASE billing.type WHEN 'A' THEN '-' ELSE billing.amount AS bed END
FROM billing
```

Answer (score 3):

One [`CASE-WHEN-THEN-ELSE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) can have only one return value...

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT billing.*,
CASE billing.type WHEN 'A' THEN billing.amount ELSE '-' END AS bes,
CASE billing.type WHEN 'A' THEN '-' ELSE billing.amount END AS bed 
FROM billing
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT billing.*,
    CASE  WHEN billing.type =  'A' THEN billing.amount ELSE 0 END AS bes,
    CASE  WHEN billing.type <> 'A' THEN billing.amount ELSE 0 END AS bed
FROM billing
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your MySQL version, you can use [IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html) or one of two different syntaxes for `CASE` [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html)(1), [CASE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html)(2).

```
SELECT *,
  (IF type = 'A' THEN amount ELSE '-' END IF) bes,
  (IF type = 'A' THEN '-' ELSE amount END IF) bed
FROM billing
```